# Excel cuts off data from log file field

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a .log file which has a column with time and many more. Example cell:

```
Time  
10:35:54,234
```

When I open the file with Excel or copy/paste into Excel what I get there is

```
Time
35:54,2
```

So it cuts off the hour and milliseconds. How do I fix this problem?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! What version of Excel are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open a blank Excel workbook, then import the file as text.

In Excel 2016, you can do this by going to the Data ribbon and clicking `From Text/CSV`. There you can browse for your log file. (If it does not show up, change the value in the dropdown from "Text Files" to "All Files".)

[image]

Then, choose the column delimiter your log file uses (e.g., tab or comma). Finally in the `Data Type Detection` field, choose `Do not detect data types`. This will import each column as text and not snip off any parts of your data.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use custom format `hh:mm:ss.000`

[image]